# Stop Icons Overlapping in the Infragistics Carousel Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, carousel, infragistics

I'm using this control to display a dynamic list of values.  The problem that I have is that the default behavior seems to be to overlap each icon to the next.  Here's my control XAML:

```
xmlns:ig="http://infragistics.com/Windows"


...


 <Grid>
    < Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        < ColumnDefinition Width ="Auto"/>
        < ColumnDefinition Width ="Auto"/>
        < ColumnDefinition Width ="Auto"/>
    </ Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    < ig:XamCarouselListBox x:Name ="myCarousel" ItemTemplate="{ DynamicResource MyTemplate }" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column ="1">

         <ig:XamCarouselListBox.Resources>               
            <DataTemplate x:Key ="MyTemplate">                    
                <Button  Click="Click_Event" Width="100" Height ="95" x:Name ="btn">
                    <Image ... />
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>               
        </ig:XamCarouselListBox.Resources >


        <ig:CarouselViewSettings ShouldScrollItemsIntoInitialPosition ="False" ItemPathHorizontalAlignment ="Center" 
              AutoScaleItemContentsToFit="False" ReserveSpaceForReflections ="False" ItemsPerPage ="5" IsNavigatorVisible ="True"
              IsListContinuous ="True">
                <ig:CarouselViewSettings.ItemPathRenderPen >
                    < Pen  />
                </ig:CarouselViewSettings.ItemPathRenderPen >
            </ig:CarouselViewSettings >               
        </ig:XamCarouselListBox.ViewSettings >           
    </ig:XamCarouselListBox>
```

I can get the effect that I want by changing the column definition to:

```
    < Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        < ColumnDefinition Width ="Auto"/>
        < ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
        < ColumnDefinition Width ="Auto"/>
    </ Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

However, that means that when there are only 2 items displayed, the carousel is far too wide.  Is there a setting for the carousel that will turn off the overlapping behaviour, or allow me to specify a margin to achieve this (I have tried putting margins in various places, but they are ignored).

Answer (score 0):

For controlling where the items stop to prevent overlap, you would could modify the path, how many items are on the path, change the scale of the items and adjust other properties.  There isn't any property on the Carousel that will simply prevent overlap.

I recommend reading the section on the [xamCarouselListBox in the help](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=xamCarouselListBox_Using_xamCarouselListBox.html) as a starting point.  The [Defining Layouts](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=xamCarouselListBox_Defining_Layouts.html) and [Designing the Look and Feel](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=xamCarouselListBox_Designing_the_Look_and_Feel.html) will help you get started understanding what can be done with the xamCarouselListBox.